# How can I mark (movie) files in finder (as watched)?

Tags: finder

In my movie folder I have loads of movies. The ones I watched I want to mark as watched. 
I suppose I could either use the colors (like green for watched) or the Spotlight tags, but I would rather have a checkbox of sorts which I could tick.
The colors and the tags I don't find all that useable. Also, I do not want to add the files to iTunes.

Is there something like this?

Comment: What's wrong with using the colour labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, No. Finder is for file management, therefore such feature will be weird. You might be able to find plugins for this, but I doubt it. Most people use iTunes to achieve such job, which you seems to be reluctant to do.

You can try making a separate iTunes library for these files, and not importing them to your new library. That might help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess deep down, I knew that but was unwilling to believe it. The piece of advice to have a second iTunes library is good, though. I will look into that.

Comment: an alternative is to use a software to manage your movie collection that provides the feature watched/not watched, Plex http://www.plexapp.com comes to mind.

Comment: Thank you @kraymer. Plex looks really interesting, I'll look into that.

Comment: @kraymer I will say Plex more a media server or a media center though.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to rely on the date last opened metadata.

In the case of torrents you want to keep seeding, you could hide the files or folders. Copy them, open Terminal, type `chflags hidden` , and press ⌘V.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the last opened data doesn't help me, since I might have edited the file and not watched it (that happens, in fact). And those files are not torrents, either.